# ¿como puedo concatenar registros de una misma columna en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

si pudieran ayudarme tengo una tabla asi:

```
identificativo        fecha
72028586            11/05/2018
72028586            13/05/2018
72045976            17/05/2018
72063798            13/05/2018
```

y necesito hacer una consulta que me muestre la tabla asi:

```
identificativo        fecha
72028586           11/05/2018, 13/05/2018
72045976           17/05/2018
72063798           13/05/2018
```

como lo hago????

Comment: No se entiende lo que preguntas

Comment: Quieres concatenar todas las fechas o solo la primera y la última?

Comment: quiero concatenar las fechas que tienen un mismo identificativo

Answer (score 3):

Pareciera que la función que estás buscando es `STRING_AGG`

```
SELECT 
  identificativo, STRING_AGG(fecha, ',') 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY identificativo;
```

Para versiones anteriores a SQL server 2017 usamos el truco del `for xml`

```
SELECT identificativo, fecha=STUFF(
  (SELECT ', ' + fecha AS [text()]
        FROM Table1 XT
        WHERE XT.identificativo = T.identificativo
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
FROM Table1 T 
GROUP BY identificativo;
```

ref: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212160/1423096

Para dejar de lado el espacio detrás de la coma, cambias estas dos lineas

```
 (SELECT ',' + fecha AS [text()]
```

...

```
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: no me funciona eso me da el siguiente error

Comment: [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @AndyMontalvo,  `STRING_AGG` es una función de SQL2017 o superior.

Comment: por eso mismo es el sql q tengo aqui es el 2014, tienes alguna idea d como hacerlo en este

Comment: ?????????????????????

Comment: ahí te agregué una forma para versiones antiguas