# Fusionar dos filas en una consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo mi consulta que me muestra mis datos de esta manera

```
select
   Nombre,
   Deporte,
   sum(Ganar),
   sum(perder)

from Tabla  
where   CodPersona = 777
group by  Nombre, deporte
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la consulta me muestra las sumas de los dos deportes y me repite los resultados para ambos el mismo valor

lo que deberia mostrar seria aslgo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes mostrar el contenido de tabla? por lo menos del codPersona 777. Por otro lado, quieres el resultado por deporte, o por todos los deportes de una persona?

Comment: @AlbertoLopez quiero mostrar los deportes que tiene una persona, por ejemplo mis deportes son 7 y varias personas tienen diferentes deportes

Answer (score 0):

Existe un truco para versiones antes de 2017  y una funcion para versiones 2017 o superior en el siguiente link.

[¿como puedo concatenar registros de una misma columna en sql server?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/como-puedo-concatenar-registros-de-una-misma-columna-en-sql-server)